# TemplateBuilder.dot Missing

Tags: ms-word, bi-publisher, xml-publisher

I have installed BI Publisher Desktop 11g for Windows. After installation I am not able to see Bi Publisher tab in MS word.
I have tried adding TemplateBuilder.dot file, however, I am not able to find this dot file on my PC which is Windows 8.1

What could be the reason?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the following folder you have install BI Publisher for Desktop:
 **Program Files (x86)\Oracle\BI Publisher\BI Publisher Desktop\DotNetInstallFiles**

Double click the setup.exe file and follow the instructions you see.
Restart the word and try again

Hope,this helps

Comment: I did what you have suggested, however, still not able to locate or see TemplateBuilder.dot file. Thanks